# Does mankind possess the technology to intentionally trigger a Yellowstone eruption?

Tags: pressure, estimation, geophysics, explosions, earthquake

The Yellowstone Caldera eruption will probably be an Extinction Level Event when it eventually happens.

[image]

Suppose some lunatic wanted to set it off now, with drills, bombs, or whatnot. Say this lunatic has the resources of a nuclear nation state at its disposal.

Is that an achievable goal? Or is Yellowstone safe until it sets itself off?

(BTW I realise that there is an Earth Science stack exchange, but I figured this is a question about the *means of triggering an eruption*, which seems more physics-y.)

Comment: I think this is too broad as it stands. I'd want to see it narrowed down to some specific detail about the physical mechanisms involved in causing a volcano to erupt, and then perhaps you could frame that question in terms of asking whether it's something humanity could trigger.